# Will vs Going to

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, will-future, will-would-meaning-wanting-to

I’m a bit baffled about these two structures: going to and will. Here’s an example of where I get confused:

Liverpool’s players are known to be skilled. They ....... the match easily.

A) will win.    B) are going to win.

What is the right answer and why?

Answer (score 2):

They both mean the same thing, and they're both correct.

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will

Answer (score -1):

Will win.

will do something means be willing to do something, not sure if it will happen or not.
be going to do means plan to do something, you know it will happen.

Comment: Surely every sports team goes into a competition/match planning to win but they don't know it will happen.